# Fabricjs copy html in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs, html2canvas

I'm working on a Prestashop module who using fabricJS,
i would like to copy a  content and appends it to an canvas with fabricJS.
I'm seen html2canvas could helpme but it's create a canvas and not append to my current Canvas.
I feel confuse, someone can help me ? 
I've tried this:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('my-div'), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);

  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Code snippets are intended for code that can run. Yours doesn't. Please edit the code snippet or do not use the code snippet functionality.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be more understandable. What exactly is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english i'm french.
I'm trying to put the content of `#my-div` to the `#canvas` but, html2canvas creates a canvas and doesn't insert in the canvas.

So this code doesn't work:

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('my-div'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
       }
    });
```

but this one does:

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('motif'), {
           onrendered: function(canvas) {
                console.log(canvas);
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
           }
    });
```

I've also tried:

```
document.getElementById('c').appendChild(canvas);
```

doesn't work either.

Once everything is ok, 
I would like to use fabricJS for put the result in a fabricJS canvas.